# SSDT and Unit Testing Stored Procedure That Accesses a Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am learning how to test T-SQL code written on SQL Server 2014 Standard using SSDT. I've used the following walkthrough to get started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx#Create%20a%20Database%20Project%20and%20Import%20a%20Schema

I have several scenarios with stored procedures accessing linked servers.

1. Read local table and write to linked server.
2. Read linked server and write to local table.
3. Read data from local table, write to another local table, write same data to linked server (similar to scenario #1).

The linked servers I'm using have a test and production environment only which poses several questions:

<strike>What would be the correct way(s) to write tests over these stored procedures?</strike>  Edit: removed for being too broad.

Should the tests interact with the linked servers or could there be mock connections somehow (similar to WebMock in Ruby)?

What would be the ideal way to setup data for a stored procedure that would normally read data from a linked server?

EDIT: I should mention that the linked servers are not SQL Server instances.

Comment: Consider using local database synonyms to access linked server objects. That would allow the synonyms to reference local database objects for unit testing or linked servers for other needs.

Comment: I'm using the syntax EXEC('select * from table') AT linked_server_name since the remote server is postgresql. Can that be accomplished with synonyms?

Comment: Unfortunately, synonyms don't apply to the EXEC...AT linked_server_name syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answers

> What would be the correct way(s) to write tests over these stored procedures?

Asking the "correct" way to write tests for a stored procedure is fairly broad, as it is primarily subjective with numerous and various ways of doing that. Ideally for each unit test you would have a script to prepare and restore the database for that specific test, but I will provide some links at the end of this answer to the official guides for configuring and running unit tests.

> Should the tests interact with the linked servers or could there be mock connections somehow (similar to WebMock in Ruby)?

Usually a test server will be linked with another test server. Data on test servers is usually refreshed from prod. (or randomly generated altogether) and randomized if it has sensitive data.

The easiest/quickest method for this would be to take a backup of the linked **test** databases and restoring them as a new database in a development environment. The linked server in your development environment would then be configured to reference the restored database. This way, you are not modifying the shared data in the your **test** environment. This could be scripted as part of your tests.

> What would be the ideal way to setup data for a stored procedure that would normally read data from a linked server?

This may be accomplished by:

1. Installing the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver.
2. Creating an ODBC Data Source for the PostgreSQL server.
3. Configuring a linked server to PostgreSQL, using a generic (but identifying) name for the linked server.

For example, In the **New Linked Server** dialog, you could specify `GENERICNAME` for the **Linked Server** field, no matter what the name/ip of the server is.

You could then read data similar to:

```
SELECT column FROM GENERICNAME.A;
SELECT column FROM GENERICNAME.B;
```

You could also use [`OPENQUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql), using `GENERICNAME` as the `linked_server` value in the syntax example `OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )`.

If you have not done this before, [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/) is a good article showing how to connect SQL Server and PostreSQL using a generic name.

### Official Microsoft Guides on SQL Server Unit Tests

Here are some links from Microsoft's documentation. Keep in mind using a generic name means this is all still applicable, your stored procedures would just be using the same linked server name, e.g. `GENERICNAME`. The actual server this references would just be different depending on the environment.

[Walkthrough: Creating and Running a SQL Server Unit Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx)

[How to: Create SQL Server Unit Tests for Functions, Triggers, and Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851215(v=vs.103).aspx)

[How to: Configure SQL Server Unit Test Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851221(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: This does not answer any of the original questions.

Comment: @eaburk Are you not asking how to create a linked server in such a way that allows your 3 scenarios to occur in different environments (test and production you mentioned) in such a way that is most ideal?

Comment: Yes, I may not have provided enough details. I have a local db for unit testing. A local db for development. A staging db for testing with users. And a prod db for deployment. My linked servers only have TEST/PROD environments. So my unit tests would run against their TEST environment (which is shared among developers). Ideally (I think) my tests could run against local DB's that mimic the linked servers. But I'm not sure that's possible to setup.

Comment: @eaburk That additional information is helpful indeed. I have updated my answer accordingly!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your post. Some thoughts:Your first answer:  My first question is likely too broad as you mentioned , but was targeted at writing stored procedures that contain logic interacting with linked servers. I have updated my post to remove that question entirely. Your second answer: I don't have the liberty of creating new environments on the linked servers as they are out of my control.Your third answer: I'm not sure how to set up data on linked servers that could be shared with other developers. That's my biggest hurdle is trying to get everything local.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-worded my response to your third question. Your third answer: I'm not sure how setting up data on linked servers that could be shared with other developers would be a reliable way to create/run tests.

Comment: @eaburk The databases wouldn't need to be set up on the linked server, you could restore the database backups to PostgreSQL anywhere, including on your local machine. You can create a linked server to localhost/127.0.0.1, just specify that IP when setting it up as an ODBC data source.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand now. That's a great tip for postgresql and any other databases that can be installed locally.

Comment: I would like to clarify one last thing for anyone listening. I have a linked server pointing to a legacy DB2 database running on an AS400. My queries have to use externally defined stored procedures that call RPG programs to convert binary fields to character so it can be used normally. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPSQF_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/evferlsh265.htm for information on why I have to do this. I promise I'm not making this up lol. I will have to figure out a workaround to write tests around this system.